# Are these 1x1x5 and 1x2x5 bricks LEGO?

Tags: part-identification

I bought a bulk box of LEGO and about 10% were mega blocks. I am unsure of these pieces. They seem to match in color.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Bricks!

Answer (score 7):

These are the Blocked Open Stud variants of

[Part # 2453a : Brick 1 x 1 x 5 - Blocked Open Stud or Hollow Stud](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=131804#T=C)

[image]

and

[Part # 2454 : Brick 1 x 2 x 5 - Blocked Open Studs or Hollow Studs](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2454#T=C)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are hollowed stud 1 x 1 x 5, and hollowed stud 1 x 2 x 5 bricks.